# Python Script to Run for ArcGIS

Tags: python, arcgis

I want to run python scripts that use geo-processing tools. I do not want to integrate them, instead I want to run scripts outside and not in ArcGIS. Please tell me how to do it with a nice example. I have to do reclassification of 4 maps and then do a weighted sum overlay of the outputs. Below is the script which I am able to write, but I don't know where I am getting an error..

```
enter code here # 

import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting
 gp = arcgisscripting.create()
 gp.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

  gp.AddToolbox("C:/../Spatial Analyst Tools.tbx")

  feature_shp1 = sys.argv[1]
  if feature_shp1 == '#':
   feature_shp1 = "D:\\BRIEFCASE\\media\\new shapefiles\\feature_shp1"
  slope = sys.argv[2]
  if slope == '#':
  slope = "D:\\" 

  Reclassification__2_ = sys.argv[3]
  if Reclassification__2_ == '#':
  Reclassification__2_ = "2 1;2 3 2;3 4 3;4 5 4" 

  Reclassification = sys.argv[4]
  if Reclassification == '#':
  Reclassification = "0 13 1;13 45 2;45 80 3;80 108 4;108 146 5;146 176;174   195 7;195 231 8;231 255 9" 

  Reclass_feat3 = "D:\\"
  Reclass_slop3 = "D:\\3"
  gjh = "C:\"
  Reclass_field = "VALUE"
  Reclass_field__2_ = "VALUE"

  gp.Reclassify_sa(feature_shp1, Reclass_field__2_, Reclassification__2_,            Reclass_feat3, "NODATA")

  gp.Reclassify_sa(slope, Reclass_field, Reclassification, Reclass_slop3, "NODATA")

  gp.WeightedSum_sa("'..Reclass_feat3' VALUE 1;'D:..Reclass_slop3' VALUE 1","ijh")
```

Comment: Please post only code without syntax errors. Your indentation is inconsistent.

Comment: Please post your error message.

Comment: First of all. You can run your python scripts from the command line or in IDLE - no tutorial needed for that. But you need to specify your problem, post a traceback,...In general you should post GIS related questions on the [GIS section](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) of SE.

Comment: sorry for late reply, Error is ..  Failed to execute. parameters are not valid. ERROR 000865: Input raster: c:/....  does not exist. Failed to execute reclassify.  This is the error. I don't get it why it is showing.

Comment: Please include your whole error message in your Question which you can **edit** - or just check the syntax of each tool you are using against what you have included in your script - there will be one of them that expects a raster where you have supplied the name of something other than a raster or of a raster that does not exist.

Comment: I think this question may be better posted on [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) if not answered acceptably here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use ArcGIS geoprocessing tools without firing up ArcGIS itself, you'll want to put the following bit of code at the top of your program:

```
import arcpy
#Rest of Program
#Step 3:Profit!
```

That should allow you to use various tools from the toolbox, including Weighted sum and Reclassification.  I think arcpy replaced arcgisscripting as the module to import for that purpose, but I'm not sure, since I haven't been using python scripting wtih ArcGIS long enough to have known anything other than arcpy.

As for how to get the toolbox tools to work, [the ArcGIS Resource center can be quite helpful](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Weighted_Sum/009z000000rr000000/).